# Lightweight framework for forms w Ajax in Python

Tags: python, ajax, forms

I'm new to Python and would like to know of some good framework / code library out there to help me out with building forms w/ ajax (and fallback to no-js) submits.

Doing it from scratch is possible ofcourse, but since this is such a common task I figured there must be some great stuff out there.

Django could be the way, but seems to big for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for built-in AJAX support like Ruby on Rails? Or are you looking for a web framework that will work well with AJAX?

If you are looking for the latter, then [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a "micro framework" that is considerably smaller than Django. There are others such as [web.py](http://webpy.org/) (again, very compact), [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) and [Turbogears](http://turbogears.org/) but I guess you'd have already considered them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a direct answer but something definitely worth a look is the wonderful pyjamas http://pyjs.org/. That's a python to js compiler that lets you build whole browser client apps in python. If used with django as the server side (you only need the model and some views) then you get front-to-back python and a strong webservice model. For something simpler php with phpolait would be fine on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

I personally made good experiences with [web.py](http://webpy.org/) in conjunction with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

web.py (Python Webframework) is very lightweight and easy to understand, writing your own Ajax requests with jQuery is not too complicated either. I used these both in my first webproject written in Python and the learning curve was nearly zero. :)